# .Net How to Set Content-Type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded with HttpClient for a GetAsync Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

Does anyone know how to set the content type for a GET async request?
I'm trying to send a GET async request for an API but cannot work out how to set the Content-Type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

This is the postman definition: [Encode GET request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPHXq.jpg)
This is the result from Postman: [202 response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObWX4.jpg)

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.domain.com/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/location/trackInfo?" + filter.URLQuery);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    trackInfo = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<TrackingInformation>>();
}
```

Comment: `GET` requests do not have bodies, and hence the `Content-Type` header does not apply. If your API wants this `Content-Type`, it's expecting a `POST`.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, this is what I thought but I was puzzled because I can use Postman to set up the Get request and I can encode the url with application/x-www-form-urlencoded - see the "202 response" link

Comment: @WarrenMintyOwl is that not the _response_ `Content-Type`?

Comment: You can technically send along a `Content-Type` header with a `GET` request -- the standard doesn't explicitly forbid it or mandate that servers should give an error response. It just doesn't mean anything. Query parameters in URLs are *always* URL-encoded; `x-www-form-urlencoded` just indicates this encoding is used in the body of a request (for `PUT` or `POST`).

Comment: OK I see. The reason I went down this path is that I receive a 404 and presumed it was the url encoding since that is the only thing different from the Postman definition - compared with Fiddler.